# How to get count of elements in xml nodes?

Tags: c#, xml

I am getting xml file from msmq and want to know the count of elements in each node. My xml looks like below. The Mode count should be 4, and then I will doing for loop to put them into a collection/list. Please help me on this issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Patient xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Mode>
    <string>51000153</string>
    <string>51002040</string>
    <string>51001475</string>
    <string>51002670</string>
  </Mode>
</Patient>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int count = xml.Descendants("string").Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use LINQ to accomplish this Task.

For the counting of the items:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("xmlfile.xml");
var count = doc.Descendants("Mode")
               .Descendants("string")
               .Count();
```

For inserting of the values into an IEnumerable:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("xmlfile.xml");
var list = doc.Descendants("Mode")
              .Descendants("string")
              .Select(node=>node.Value)
              .ToList();
```

Comment: A bit of a mixed approach here. Either specify the complete path with Element()/Elements() or use one Descendants()

Answer (score 0):

Here how you got the count

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("xmlstr");
int count = doc.Elements("string").Count();
```

you can put these elements into list without looping

```
IEnumerable<XElement> list = doc.Elements("string").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `XmlNodeList` type and `GetElementsByTagName` method , below is small example from `MSDN`

```
.............
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement; // Doc is `XmlDocument`
XmlNodeList elemList = root.GetElementsByTagName("title");
for (int i=0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
{   
  Console.WriteLine(elemList[i].InnerXml);
}
```

for more information open link below

[XmlNodeList.Count Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodelist.count(v=vs.110).aspx)